# Data not clustering but overlapping in histogram in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, cluster-computing, histogram

I have this kind of data:

```
![#Size conc    Cumconc Midpoint Diameter   conc    Cumconc Midpoint Diameter   conc    Cumconc
0.337   1788.647911 2679394.57  0.337   1583.950394 1085006.02  0.337   846.9754269 1333139.322
0.419   671.5617583 1005999.514 0.419   604.4813591 414069.731  0.419   353.3910197 556237.465
0.522   227.8372837 341300.251  0.522   192.4245766 131810.835  0.522   198.8547746 312997.4152
0.65    71.93152603 107753.426  0.65    58.52586701 40090.2189  0.65    71.10833659 111924.5218
0.809   39.83629606 59674.7715  0.809   28.31269255 19394.1944  0.809   49.12599943 77324.3231
0.997   26.33886829 39455.6247  0.997   17.56852188 12034.43749 0.997   40.27617821 63394.7045
1.244   10.69495002 16021.03513 1.244   7.027818774 4814.05586  1.244   15.75314508 24795.45036
1.562   8.939251215 13390.99832 1.562   5.863628745 4016.58569  1.562   12.25755549 19293.39234
1.944   9.94324986  14894.98829 1.944   6.499851182 4452.39806  1.944   12.77541752 20108.50717
2.421   6.101436322 9139.95161  2.421   4.063535022 2783.52149  2.421   7.203576353 11338.42918
3.014   3.4049672   5100.640866 3.014   2.2726694   1556.778539 3.014   3.770140212 5934.200693
3.752   1.987458835 2977.213335 3.752   1.330344839 911.286215  3.752   2.04306203  3215.779635
4.672   1.150321425 1723.181494 4.672   0.756771709 518.3886204 4.672   1.126466957 1773.058991
5.816   0.540065081 809.017492  5.816   0.352022917 241.1356981 5.816   0.508609852 800.5519074
7.241   0.358084214 536.4101523 7.241   0.228796404 156.7255369 7.241   0.336493494 529.6407603
9.015   0.257702054 386.0376766 9.015   0.153762399 105.3272433 9.015   0.233477387 367.493407][1]
```

and I'm trying to generate a clustered plot in gnuplot with the following code:

```
set key top center
set xlabel "Dp (nm)"
set ylabel "Concentration (#/cm^3)"
set format y  "%.1tE%+03T"
set autoscale  
set logscale xy

set boxwidth 0.5 relative
set style data histogram
set style fill solid border -1
set style histogram clustered gap 1

plot "sample.dat" u (1000*$1):2 t 'data1' w boxes lc 2,\
      "" u (1000*$4):5 t 'data2' w boxes lc 5

pause -1
```

However, I obtain a staked plot, no matter what.

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Of course you don't get a stacked plot, because the `w boxes` overwrites the globally set `histogram` style. Note however, that the `histogram` style doesn't support numerical axes in general, but the boxes are placed at integer x-values and manually given an xticlabel.

Comment: OK, I understand. I changed it to xtics and without boxes . However, now I cannot show logarithmic scale. I must decide what do I prefer.